# Python Performing calculation on every x line and place it back into original file

Tags: python, file

I have a list that looks like this

```
url1
number1
number2
number3
url2
number1
number2
number3
url3
etc
```

I want to perform calculations on number 2 , and replace it with the new value in the original position of the text file. Here is what i have so far

```
import itertools

#with open('math.txt', 'r') as f:
#       fourthlines = itertools.islice(f, 2, None, 4)
#       for line in fourthlines:
#               line=float(line)
#               #print line
#               line=((line-100)/2)
#               print line
```

Issue: this returns the value i want but i want to place it back into math.txt where it came from ( number 2's position )

Comment: You could write to another file as you are reading from that one. You could read the whole file into memory do the operations, and write back to that file over writing everything. There are a few other choices.

Answer (score 0):

First writing to another file:

```
with open("test.txt","r") as rp, open("write.txt","w") as wp:
    for line_count, line in enumerate(rp,-2):
        if line_count % 4 == 0:
            print(line)
            #do somethign to line
            wp.write('found the line number 2\n')
        else:
            wp.write(line)
```

Second, using a temp file modifying the original one, temp files are the safest way of modifying a file:

```
import tempfile

temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="r+")
with open("test.txt","r") as rp:
    for line_count, line in enumerate(rp,-2):
        if line_count % 4 == 0:
            print(line)
            #do somethign to line
            line = 'found the line number 2'
            temp_file.write(line + '\n')
        else:
            temp_file.write(line)

temp_file.seek(0) #reset the tempfile's cursor back to the start
with open("test.txt","w") as wp:
    for line in temp_file:
        wp.write(line)
```

In either case just change "test.txt" to your text file name, and where I put `#do something to line` just do whatever you need to do making sure line is a `str` at the end after doing things to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [read/write](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) mode for python file objects.

```
fo = open("foo.txt",'r+')
```

However, **THIS DOES NOT INSERT NEW TEXT INTO A FILE**, instead it writes over what is already there. For example.

```
******original text file*****
hello world!
*****************************

fo = open("foo.txt",'r+')
fo.write('spam')
fo.close()

***********result************
spamo world!
*****************************
```

I would not use this on a plain text file unless I knew 100% that the data I was writing was the same size as the data that I was replacing. Even then, I would hesitate. If you are set on storing your information as plain text then I think you would be better off writing to a separate file.

On the other hand, if you change your information so it is stored in binary form and the original value and the new value have the same byte size then I think that this would be a good option for you to consider.

Answer (score 0):

*My solution will does the **calculation and write it at the same time without using temp file**.*

**Solution has two parts :**

1. It will first take the lines from file on which the operation need to be done.
2. Second, it read file and do the operation on above list of lines and write the new value at the same time i.e. it is going to in place replacement.

**Module** : `fileinput`

Using this module you can to do reading and writing to file at the same time.
[Check here for more info !!!](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html)

**Content of math.txt before :**

```
url
1
2
3
url
4
5
6
url
```

**Code:**

```
import fileinput

lines_to_check = []

#First - It will take out the lines on which operation is required
with open("math.txt","r") as fh:
    for l_count, line in enumerate(fh,-2):
        if l_count % 4 == 0:
            lines_to_check.append(line.strip())

#Second - Calculate and write
#As calculation, I am just multiplying value by 100
for line in fileinput.input('math.txt',inplace=1):
    if line.strip() in lines_to_check:
        line=float(line)
        line= line *100
        print str(line).strip()
    else:
        print line.strip()
```

**Content of math.txt after executing code :**

```
url1
1
200.0
3
url2
4
500.0
6
url3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a safe way to do it...which is the approach *I'd* take as *I* am a beginner.

1. Open the file and read its lines into a list (`filename.readlines()` method).
2. Lookup the element's index in the list (`lines.index(element)` method).
3. Replace the element in the list (`list[index]=new_element`).
4. Open the file and [over]write all the lines from you list back into it.

If the file is not extremely long then this method should be sufficient.
I hope this helps you, if not then I am sure it will benefit someone even newer than me. (;